# Reading Exchange Policies

Tags: exchange-server

Is there an API to read programmatically settings/policies from a given exchange server? Like [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297964.aspx) one.

It doesn't seem like there's an API via EWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only API for this are the Powershell cmdlets.